# In AllDup → Search Method, how does "Pixel" differ from "Comparison Size"?

Tags: terminology

Please see the options underlined in red and green. If "Pixel" (red) refers to "Picture area", then what does "Comparison size" (green) mean?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Often I have
an "original" high-resolution digital photograph around 4000 x 3000 pixels,
and from it I've created
a lower-resolution "web scale" image downscaled to 400 x 300 pixels,
a similar-looking 400 x 300 pixel image
dithered to use 216 (obsolete) "web-safe colors" (lower color depth),
and "the same" image in thumbnail form downscaled to around 80x60 pixels.

If I'm reading
the ["Find Similar Pictures"](https://www.alldup.de/alldup_help/search_similar_pictures.php) section of the manual
correctly,
you've selected
one of the AllDup options to detect that all 4 of the above files are "similar"
by creating a temporary 24x24 pixel image downscaled from each one,
and then only comparing a 16x16 pixel square
cut out of the the lower-right corner of each tiny image
to corresponding 16x16 pixel squares from each of the other images.

p.s.:
You can get answers *much* more quickly
if you post a link to the manual for the software you're using.
In this case,
[The AllDup Manual](https://www.alldup.de/alldup_help/).